# Can't find menu to change to left click select

Tags: customization

I really love new left click, but in new 2.8 beta I can't find a menu for changing it.

The only way I found is to load factory settings on each start of 2.8 beta.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to go to Edti > Preferences > Keymap > Select With[image]

Hope that helps.

Good Luck

Comment: OOH thanks i was searching for it on Input menu, thanks